# Drupal website hacked, but cannot find source?

Tags: php, linux, drupal-7, malware

I got mail from Google Webmaster tools that strange URLs where indexed. URLs like mywebsite.com/cheap-medicine/, etc.

I have a Drupal website and I can see those URLs are indexed. And using proxy I can see the page myself. However, I cannot find the source.

- I have looked into a bunch of files but they are unchanged.
- Also I searched my entire database and of course looked into Drupal backend for strange content.
- I even searched my entire server using Linux grep, also no result for words on the page. The database URL `/` routing tables also show no strange URLs.
- I did of course also check `.htaccess` files

How are these URLs accessible if I cannot find them anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Look into your .htaccess file, it contains a lot of power. It can make these strange URIs mask themselves. Try to check the validity of that file.  This might be where this is coming from.

If your .htaccess file, or any .htaccess file inside any subdirectory of the site weren't hacked on then you probably want to reinstall the Drupal core.  If you followed proper development practice by never editing third party core files, then you will not lose any work or time, because it will be a fresh default copy of what you installed the first time.

After this, make sure core runs correctly in a default state, and that the problem is gone. Then you can copy back in your source files to your Drupal framework and reconfigure and resume.

If the problem comes back after you put your source files back, then the problem is in your sources.

You can also try grepping for the terms individually i.e. `grep -rin "medicine" ./*` on a GNU/Linux box to see if these terms show up.

Comment: Hi, Why the downvote (if it was you)? I of course checked .htaccess, was the first thing i checked and nothing in it.. What else could it be? I also already tried the grep..

Comment: @user2897757: it's best not to start guessing who has downvoted you. Downvoting on Stack Overflow is a normal occurrence, and you should not worry about the odd one or two. The question is hard to answer from the information given, so maybe that's why someone downvoted - we can only guess.

Comment: @halfer, ok, I get it :)

Brian,thanks a lot mate. I will do some more digging into other .htaccess files as well. The grep does not return any results unfortunately (except from some spam mails on the server)

Comment: Ok, so I think they changed a bunch of core Durpal modules. My Drupal was a little outdated so maybe a plugin or even the core has been hacked. I will revert a full website backup of a month ago, update everything and see if it has been solved..

Comment: I have also faced similar issue recently.  So I have checked which files are modified within last 24 hrs using command `find /directory_path -mtime -1 -ls`. Then disabled PHP filter module using Drush. Then finally I have installed [drupal security module](https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review)

Comment: ugh, they changed teh core modules.  this may or may not be the point of your vulnerability, but it is certainly the point of your headache.  im sorry to hear they edited core files.  what you will have to do is to identify which core files were edited, by doing diffs or something, then i after your fresh installation of drupal,  pull back in those edits, ONLY after looking for HACKS on those very pages..

Comment: by the way, if you get that far, as a suggestion,  you might want to copiously note those edits, and the location of them, so they can be pulled out asap when you find the time..  then you wont have that problem ever again.  this takes time however, but you can slowly replace those edits in core properly into modules or other outside-core areas of the code base.  then you wont have to hesitate to update core.